# How can I know if a cell of UITableView is selected?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I am writing an app in Swift with XCode. It includes a `UITableView`. Just one question - in Swift, how can I tell what cell is selected by the user?

To clarify:

1. A user selects the cell with the label "foo"
2. The code should return "foo", or whatever is selected by the user

Comment: did you tried the below approach ?

Comment: @bllakjakk Thanks! Will try as soon as I have time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell what cell is selected by User by adding following function in your view controller.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
...

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
}

...
```

}

So now it depends that whether you are having an array to display the text names of each cell. If yes you can use this indexPath.row to retrieve the text of the row user selected.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var tableView : UITableView!
    var data:String[] = ["Cell 1","Cell 2","Cell 3","Cell 4"]


func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        let cell : UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.text = self.data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
         println("SELECTED INDEX /(indexPath.row)")
         println("Selected Cell Text /(data[indexPath.row])")
}
```

Comment: No, you add the function to the table view delegate.

Comment: Please check my UIViewController definition again. It already implements the delegate and hence define the functions.

Comment: But not everyone does it that way.  The function goes with the delegate, not the table view.  And it's important to keep the concepts clear.

Comment: I think you should check the apple sample: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/createconfiguretableview/createconfiguretableview.html

Comment: I'm not saying that you can't combine the delegate (and data source) with the controller.  I'm saying that, regardless of how you combine them, that function is logically part of the delegate.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you have the indexPath of the cell in question - eg from within any of your UITableViewDelegate or UITableViewDataSource methods,

```
BOOL selected = [tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows containsObject:indexPath];
```